# What is the intersection of an element of a collection with the collection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've always wanted to learn axiomatic set theory so I've started reading a book *Set theory and its philosophy* by Potter. I'm having trouble understanding the concepts of accumulation, levels, and histories. The following is quoted from page 41.

> **Definition.** $\text{acc}(a)=\{x : x \text{ is an individual or } (\exists b\in a)(x\in b \text{ or } x\subseteq b)\} $ (the *accumulation* of $a$).
>
> **Definition.** $\mathcal{V}$ is called a history if $(\forall V\in \mathcal{V})(V=\text{acc}(\mathcal{V}\cap V))$.

Question: What does all this look like? Can someone give me a simple example? Due to my confusion, I may be uncertain about what my real question is. I think I might really be asking the question: *Can someone give me a model of Scott-Potter Set Theory*? I'd like to see an example of a collection that is history.

Define $U=\text{(the collection of all individuals)}$ and $A_i\subseteq U$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$ any collection of individuals. Are the following statements correct?

1) $\text{acc}(\emptyset)=U\cup\{\emptyset\}$. 
2) $\text{acc}(\{A_1\})=U\cup\{x : x \text{ is a subcollection of } A_1 \}$ 
3) $\text{acc}(\{A_1,A_2\})=U\cup\{A_1,A_2\}\cup\{x : x \text{ is a subcollection of either } A_1 \text{ or } A_2 \}$. 
4) $\text{acc}\left(\Big\{\{0,1\},\{1\}\Big\}\right)=\Bigg\{\emptyset,0,1,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\Bigg\}$, (in our 'two individual universe').

Am I making a mistake?

My confusion started here: If $V\in\mathcal{V}$, then $V$ is either an individual or a collection (containing some elements which can be either individuals of other collections). What is $V\cap\mathcal{V} \ $? It seems like it should just be $V$. However, maybe it is the collection of elements which are in both $V$ and $\mathcal{V}$ excluding $V$, i.e. $V\notin V\subseteq V\cap\mathcal{V}$.

How do I notate an example of a collection? Is the following example ok? Consider a simple case where there only exist two individuals: $0$ and $1$ (am I allowed to do that?). Consider the collection:
$$\mathcal{V}=\Bigg\{\emptyset, 0, \{0\}, \{0,1\}, \Big\{0,1,\{0\},\{1\}\Big\}\Bigg\}.$$
If we take $V=\{0,1\}\in\mathcal{V}$, then $V\cap\mathcal{V}=\{0\}$, hence 
$$ \text{acc}(V\cap\mathcal{V})=\text{acc}(\{0\})=\{\emptyset, 0,1,\{0\}\}\neq V.$$ 
Therefor $\mathcal{V}$ is not a history.

Could the following be a history for a universe with a sole individual, $0$?
$$\mathcal{V}=\Bigg\{\{\emptyset,0\},\Big\{\emptyset,0,\{\emptyset\},\{0\},\big\{\emptyset,0\big\}\Big\}\Bigg\}=\{V_1,V_2\}.$$
So that $\text{acc}(V_1\cap\mathcal{V})=\text{acc}(\emptyset)=V_1$ and $\text{acc}(V_2\cap\mathcal{V})=\text{acc}(\{\emptyset,0\})=V_2$.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to the clarification by @Mauro ALLEGRANZA below, I have concluded that:

The following would be the 'third' history for a universe with a no individuals.
$$\mathcal{V}=\Bigg\{\big\{\emptyset\big\},\Big\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\Big\}\Bigg\}=\{V_1,V_2\}.$$

The following would be the 'second' history for a universe with a sole individual, $0$.
$$\mathcal{V}=\Bigg\{\{0\},\Big\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\Big\}\Bigg\}=\{V_1,V_2\}.$$
And the 'third' history would be
$$\mathcal{V}=\Bigg\{\{0\},\Big\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\Big\},\Big\{0,\emptyset,\{0\},\{\emptyset\},\{\{0\}\},\Big\{0,\emptyset\Big\},\Big\{0,\{0\}\Big\},\Big\{\emptyset,\{0\}\Big\},\Big\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\Big\}\Big\}\Bigg\}=\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}.$$

Comment: So $A\in A$ is a proper meaningful statement? I'm under the impression that a set/collection cannot be a member of itself (or we get membership ad infinitum). If $A\subset B$ but $A\in B$ also, then $A\cap B=A$, and you are saying that it is possible that $A\in A$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I have to read your text again, it must have been the elements if that element itself is a set otherwise the intersection makes no sense.

Comment: Clarification: $\{0\}\cap\{\{0\}\}=\emptyset$ but $\{0\}\cap\{0,\{0\}\}=\{0\}$, correct? Yes, the element of the collection can be a collection itself or an individual, I believe. That brings up a good question about whether we can intersect individuals. Presumably, if $a$ is an individual and $B$ is anything, then $a\cap B=\emptyset$ by convention since $a$ has no members (it's an individual, not a collection). I think if we consider 'fusions' as opposed to collections, then $a=\{a\}$, i.e. a fusion is identical to its members. Is that meaningful?

Comment: A comment regarding $acc(a)$ : "of course" the concept of *accumulation* has no significance if $a$ is not a *collection* (a set). The definition is written in order to include all individuals in any *accumulation*, but the real "value" is to include in $acc(a)$ elements and subsets of $a$. Starting from the "ground level" $V_0$ we have in it only individuals and $\emptyset$, prior to the introduction of the axioms allowing for the existence of more collections.

Comment: Thus, it seems to me that $acc(\emptyset)=U$, in your example, because, in order to have $\emptyset \in acc(\emptyset)$, we must have : $\exists b \in \emptyset$, which is not...

Comment: That's probably an error on my part! If $U$ is the set of all individuals, then $\emptyset\notin\emptyset$, therefore $\emptyset\notin acc(\emptyset)=U=acc(A)$ for any $A\subseteq U$. However $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$, therefore $\emptyset\in acc(\{\emptyset\})=U\cup\{\emptyset\}$. Therefore the most basic history is $\mathcal{V}=\{ U\}$ since $U\cap\{ U\}=\emptyset$ and $acc(\emptyset)=U$. However, I am failing at buiding a larger history. Any hints or examples of histories are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the "model" $\mathsf{ZU}$ is nothing more than the "standard" *cumulative hierarchy* with the additional "presence" of *individuals*.

The standard cumulative hierarchy is made of the $\emptyset$ (at the bottom of the hierarchy) and with every level made form the previous one by the power-set operation $\mathfrak P$.

Thus :

- "ground" level ($0$ elements) : $\emptyset$
- "first" level ($2^0=1$ element) : $\mathfrak P(\emptyset) = \{ \emptyset \}$
- "second" level ($2^1=2$ elements) : $\mathfrak P(\{ \emptyset \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$
- and so on.

In the model $\mathsf{ZU}$ of *Scott-Potter set theory* we have the :

- "ground" level $V_0 = \{ \text {the set of all individuals} \}$

The **Axiom of Separation** licenses the existence of the set $\emptyset$, and the existence of $V_0$ is licensed by the existence of $acc(\emptyset)$.

We have that only *individuals* belong to it.

Consider $\emptyset$; by def of $acc(a)$, we have that :

> $acc(\emptyset) = \{ \ x \mid x \ \text {is an individual or} \ \exists b[b \in \emptyset \to (x \in b \lor x \subseteq b)] \ \}$.

But for no $b$ we have $b \in \emptyset$; thus $\emptyset \notin acc(\emptyset)$.

Thus, with your example where $U = \{ 0,1 \}$, we have that :

> $V_0 = \{ 0,1 \}$.

What happens if we "delete" the *individuals* from $V_0$ ? Nothing is left, i.e. $V_0$ "collapses" into $\emptyset$. Thus, in $\mathsf{ZU}$ the ground level $V_0$ corresponds to the "standard" ground level $\emptyset$ of the *cumulative hierarchy*.

By **Separation**, any collection $= \{ \ x \mid x \ \text {is an individual and} \ \Phi(x) \}$ is a set; thus we have the sets : $\emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0,1 \}$, i.e. the usual elements of the power-set of a two-elements set.

Where are they located ? I suppose in $V_1$.

An *history* is (intuitively) the collection of all previous level; thus, consider $\mathcal V =$ the history of $V_0$.

We have :

> $\mathcal V = \{ V_0 \} = \{ \{ 0,1 \} \}$

and we have to check that for $(\forall V \in \mathcal V)(V=acc(V \cap \mathcal V))$.

But in $\mathcal V$ there is only one element $V$, i.e. $\{ 0,1 \}$, and $\{ 0,1 \} \cap \mathcal V = \{ 0,1 \} \cap \{ \{ 0,1 \} \} = \emptyset$.

Thus $acc(V \cap \mathcal V)=acc(\emptyset)= \{ 0,1 \} = V$.

The "next" level $V_1$ must be the *accumulation* of $\mathcal V$, i.e.

> $V_1=acc(\{ V_0 \})=acc(\{ \{ 0,1 \} \})$.

Again we have to "throw in" all the individuals, and thus $0,1 \in V_1$.

But now the second condition in the definition of *accumulation* applies, and we have to "throw in" also :

*(i)* the elements belonging to the collections in $V_1$: but only $\{ 0,1 \} \in V_1$ and we have $0,1$ already; and

*(ii)* the subcollections of the collections in $V_1$; the subcollections of $\{ 0,1 \}$ are exactly : $\emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0,1 \}$.

In conclusion :

> $V_1=acc(\{ V_0 \})=acc(\{ \{ 0,1 \} \}) = \{ \ 0,1, \emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0,1 \} \ \}$.

Again, if we delete the *individuals*, we are left with $\{ \emptyset \} = \mathfrak P(\emptyset)$.

Comment: This is very helpful! However, I am really interested in an example of a nontrivial *history*. Can you give one? $\mathcal{V}=\{U,V,\ldots\}$ where $V$ is some set such that $acc(V\cap\mathcal{V})=V$. I get that $U\subset V$. However, I have trouble including any sets in $V$. I think I am missing some basic fact.

Comment: So then, using your definitions of $V_i$, $i=0,1$, is $\mathcal{V}=\{V_0,V_1\}$ an *history*? So that $V_0\cap\mathcal{V}=\emptyset$ with $acc(\emptyset)=V_0$ and $V_1\cap\mathcal{V}=\{V_0\}$, therefor $acc(\{V_0\})=V_1$? This was my original intuition. I think I found a mistake I was making. In the one-individual universe, $\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\}\cap\{\{0\},\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\}\}=\{\{0\}\}$ not $\{0\}$! And $acc(\{\{0\}\})=\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\}$, therefore $\mathcal{V}=\{\{0\},\{0,\emptyset,\{0\}\}\}$ is the 'second' history. It's pretty embarrassingly simple, really... Thanks for your help!

Comment: One last question, if you feel so inclined: $\mathcal{V}=\{V_0,V_1,V_2\}$ is a history, but $\mathcal{V}=\{V_1,V_2\}$ is not a history; $\{\emptyset\}\notin acc(\big\{\{\emptyset,\{0\}\}\big\})$, but $\{\emptyset\}\in acc(\big\{\{0\},\{\emptyset,\{0\}\}\big\})$, yes?

Comment: I think the last bit of my above comment is true with $\emptyset$ not $\{\emptyset\}$.